# CakePHP stylish pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, styling

How in `$paginator->numbers()` change class for current page? (No is class="current")?
And How remove span tag from pagination? When I use `tag=false` i get results with open/close tag: `<>`

Comment: Don't think that this would be possible without overwriting the PaginationHelper. Just one question... why? What's wrong with "current" and "<span></span>"?

Answer (score 1):

you can modify it with css, so there is no reason to delete any tags or change internal structures.
if you do that, this will cause issues after a cake update and you will have to change everything again and again.

Comment: Guys, my question is about How can change name of class. I know i can change by css..., but i applied naming convetion like parent / parent-child / child-subchild, etc.